# how to increase memory limit in Visual Studio C++

Tags: visual-studio, memory-management

Need Help.I'm stuck at a problem when running a C++ code on Windows- Visual Studio.

When I run that code in Linux environment, there is no restriction on the memory I am able to allocate dynamically(till the size available in RAM).

But on VS Compiler, it does not let me create an array beyond a limited size.
I've tried /F option and 20-25 of google links to increase memory size but they dont seem to help much.

I am currently able to assign only around 100mb out of 3gb available.

If there is a solution for this in Windows and not in Visual Studio's compiler, I will be glad to hear that as I have a CUDA TeslaC2070 card which is proving to be pretty useless on Windows as I wanted to run my CUDA/C++ code on Windows environment.

Here's my code. it fails when LENGTH>128(no of images 640x480pngs. less than 0.5mb each. I've also calculated the approximate memory size it takes by counting data structures and types used in OpenCV and by me but still it is very less than 2gb). stackoverflow exception. Same with dynamic allocation. I've already maximized the heap and stack sizes.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <cv.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <highgui.h>

#include <cuda.h>
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#define LENGTH 100
#define SIZE1 640   
#define SIZE2 480
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


__global__ void square_array(double *img1_d, long N)
{

int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

img1_d[idx]= 255.0-img1_d[idx];

}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   
        IplImage *img1[LENGTH];
        // Open the file.
        for(int i=0;i<LENGTH;i++)
        {   img1[i] = cvLoadImage("abstract3.jpg");}




    CvMat *mat1[LENGTH];
    for(int i=0;i<LENGTH;i++)
    {
        mat1[i] = cvCreateMat(img1[i]->height,img1[i]->width,CV_32FC3 );
        cvConvert( img1[i], mat1[i] );
    }


    double a[LENGTH][2*SIZE1][SIZE2][3];

    for(int m=0;m<LENGTH;m++)
    {
    for(int i=0;i<SIZE1;i++)
    {
         for(int j=0;j<SIZE2;j++)
         {
               CvScalar scal = cvGet2D( mat1[m],j,i);
               a[m][i][j][0] = scal.val[0];
               a[m][i][j][1] = scal.val[1];
               a[m][i][j][2] = scal.val[2];

               a[m][i+SIZE1][j][0] = scal.val[0];
               a[m][i+SIZE1][j][1] = scal.val[1];
               a[m][i+SIZE1][j][2] = scal.val[2];

            }

    }   }

//cuda
double *a_d;
int N=LENGTH*2*SIZE1*SIZE2*3;

cudaMalloc((void **) &a_d, N*sizeof(double));
cudaMemcpy(a_d, a, N*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
int block_size = 370;
int n_blocks = N/block_size + (N%block_size == 0 ? 0:1);
cout<<n_blocks<<block_size;
square_array <<< n_blocks, block_size >>> (a_d, N);
cudaMemcpy(a, a_d, N*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

//cuda end



char name[]= "Image: 00000";
name[12]='\0';
int x=0,y=0;
for(int m=0;m<LENGTH;m++)
{
for (int i = 0; i < img1[m]->width*img1[m]->height*3; i+=3) 
{ 
 img1[m]->imageData[i]= a[m][x][y][0];
 img1[m]->imageData[i+1]= a[m][x][y][1];
 img1[m]->imageData[i+2]= a[m][x][y][2];

  if(x==SIZE1)
  {
  x=0;
  y++;
  }
x++;
}

    switch(name[11])
    {
        case '9': switch(name[10])
        {
            case '9': 
            switch(name[9])
            {
                case '9': name[11]='0';name[10]='0';name[9]='0';name[8]++;
                break;
                default : name[11]='0';
                name[10]='0';
                name[9]++;
            }break;

            default : name[11]='0'; name[10]++;break;
            }

            break;
        default : name[11]++;break;
    }
        // Display the image.
        cvNamedWindow(name, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        cvShowImage(name,img1);
    //cvSaveImage(name ,img1);
}
        // Wait for the user to press a key in the GUI window.
        cvWaitKey(0);

        // Free the resources.
        //cvDestroyWindow(x);
        //cvReleaseImage(&img1);
    //cvDestroyWindow("Image:");
        //cvReleaseImage(&img2);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show a code example. You haven't even told us what the limit is.

Comment: Have you tried setting the heap and stack reserve sizes under your Project Properties -> Linker -> System?

Comment: yes I have set them to maximum possible. Also, there it says to use /F command in compile options. I've tried that too. I have around 6gb of memory available in tesla for compute. I just need a way to live up to that memory in windows.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I've uploaded the code. Could you please help me on that. I really need to get this issue sorted as I have been stuck on it for past 6 months. The code runs fine for 2-3days on Linux. I can also upload VS settings screenshots if you need them. thanks in advance for help.

Comment: My C++ is too rusty to help much. What lines do the problems happen on?

Comment: double a[LENGTH][2*SIZE1][SIZE2][3]; gives error when length>128

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are allocating a huge multidimensional array on the stack in your main function (double a[..][..][..]). Do not allocate this much memory on the stack. Use malloc/new to allocate on the heap.

Comment: OpenCV has its own stack implementations which I do not have any control upon. Please help. thanks

Comment: I'm telling you that it is the array that you declare yourself that is the problem.

Comment: Ok. I totally understand what you mean, but it is not possible for me to post every code here, as I am not totally sure how this site works. I have been stuck on this problem for past 6months and have tried a very simple opencv code in which I input 300 images and save them back. and that code is also not working. I agree that in this code double plays a role in stack but it is also from opencv.

Comment: Moving the array to the heap will fix the first error. If you have further problems, please provide the details for them. If you have another example that fails you should post that one as well.