# need a code to dynamically allocate >1gb memory array in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to increase memory limit in Visual Studio C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237184/how-to-increase-memory-limit-in-visual-studio-c)

When I use without CUDA/OpenCV, I cannot initialize this code.

```
  #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
    double *arr,*arr2,*arr3;
    arr=new double[100000000];
    arr2=new double[100000000];
    arr3=new double[100000000];
    //std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x001ff700 error is what I get when I try to allocate 2.4gb out of 3.3gb available.
    return 0;
    }
```

I am not complaining about the compatibilites of Linux vs Windows, I just want to make this code run on a Windows server machine, so I am open to any C++ compiler for Windows in which such kind of limits do not occur. 
thanks

Comment: Please post your allocation code.

Comment: that code was a single line of a majorly CUDA/OpenCV based code which worked perfectly on gcc. I get stack overflow when I do malloc or new. Also I get stackoverflow when I try to get too much images in OpenCV format(please see memory limit issue link of this post).

Comment: In the code you posted there you allocate **1.4 GB** of memory *on stack*. You can't do that. I don't believe you get stackoverflow when you use malloc, perhaps another error, or perhaps you don't understand something. Anyway this is why you should post only the relevant *minimal* code that reproduces the problem. Also make sure you *compile the application for x64*, not "Win32". For some reason Visual studio compiles for 32-bit by default.

Comment: The cause of this is exactly the same as his previous question, despite the titles.

Comment: @Mooing Duck:I'm sorry but I am new to this forum and I have mentioned that question myself in the link(memory limit issue).

Comment: @ybungalobill: posting very simplified problem code in 5min. thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Also what worked on GCC and/or another platform is irrelevant for this issue, since the standard does not guarantee the allocation limits and all such details (in fact it can't).

Comment: This is not a forum, and it's highly discouraged to ask the same question twice. Edit the original question if you need to expand and/or clarify something.

Comment: I am new here and definitely wouldnt want to put same questions again but at least please give a look at both of them. In this particular question, I am not concerned about anything but dynamic memory allocation. On the other hand, In my other question, for >128 images, OpenCV was failing too due to it's stacks implementation(which is totally internal to that library and I am not in a phase to sway off my original project and edit OpenCV for total heap thing.).If someone is still uncomfortable with it then please comment after this, I'll remove this post. sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: @paercebal:thank you very much. I guess I made too many edits and was unclear in expressing my doubts. I have been stuck on these problems for past 6 months and have joined stackoverflow majorly for that. It makes me really happy to see that you took your time in understanding both questions in my haphazard language description.

Comment: **This is not an "exact duplicate".** The other "duplicate" question is about allocation on stack, which expects a quite different answer than this one, which is about allocating memory on the heap.

Comment: I did an error on calculations (too much zeroes, I guess): On a normal 32-bit Windows, without the LARGEADDRESSAWARE option (which exists for a good reason), you can allocate only 2Gb (see rounin's answer). Now, you are trying to allocate 2.4 Gb, so it will fail. Your solution is either to try the LARGEADDRESSAWARE trick and hope you'll never go beyond that 3Gb limit (which can vary from one Windows to another, IIRC) as suggested by rounin, or move to 64-bit as suggested by ybungalobill.

Comment: largeaddressaware,/f/Zm etc and many such flags have been set accordingly before I posted this. As I said I made too much edits in this post and messed it up. thanks anyways. It would be really helpful if you could guide me to a tutorial or something to setup a new project from scratch(with such settings) or an similar alternative to gcc for windows.

Comment: Sorry, I have no info. In this, Google is your friend. But I recall LARGEADDRESSSAWARE needs a compiler option to be set, and needs the Windows on which the binary will be executed to be booted with a certain option. Seriously, if you're dealing with such amounts of memory, going to 64-bit is the best solution (if you can afford a 64-bit Windows, that is)

Comment: i've mailed a few nvidia developers regarding this too but they are too busy for these problems. I am on a 64bit Windows ( HP Z.400 server machine with a Tesla C2070). thanks. I guess I'll have to find another way to solve my problems.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7558/discussion-between-paercebal-and-daerty0153)

Comment: I tried your code on a VS2010 64-bit C++ console application, and it works fine. You should review your project options, perhaps comparing them with a simple "hello world" 64-bit project.

Answer (score 4):

Is this for x86? Have you tried turning on [LARGEADDRESSAWARE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz223b1z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)? Sometimes that helped me get larger allocations to work.

Comment: I believe this is for addresses >2gb. I am happy with 1-2gb limits. I am not able to reach there. stackoverflow on crossing around 200mb.

Comment: This helped when I already had ~1GB, and was trying to make a largish alloc that would not have pushed me over the 2 GB limit. Yeah, I guess not quite the same problem if you have trouble with the first 200mb  alloc....

Answer (score 2):

There should be no problem allocating memory of that size on the CPU. If malloc isn't working for a couple of 100MB something is seriously wrong. What is the memory usage of your program? Could it be heavily fragmented or maybe you leak memory?

Why would you get a stack overflow when allocating from the heap? Are you using alloca?

You could try the VirtualAlloc family of functions that allocate whole pages directly.

EDIT: After looking at your previous question I see that you are declaring a huge multidimensional array on the stack in your main function (double a[..][..][..]). This is most likely the culprit as you get a stack overflow. Do not allocate this much memory on the stack. Allocate it on the heap instead (using malloc/new).

Answer (score 2):

The limits you posted and the 32-bit memory address in the error message (`0x001ff700`) indicate that you've compiled a 32 bit version of your application, which is the default in Visual Studio. Please configure Visual Studio to target x64. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for details.